# import package does not work with 'latex' but works with 'pdflatex' command, any solution?

Tags: import

I am using the add-on `import` package of Donald Arseneau to typeset my thesis while allowing each thesis chapter files to be placed in a subfolder. Using this package lets me do it when I typeset my document with `pdflatex` but not with `latex`. It does not look for the files in the nested folders and complains that they are not found. Is there a solution to this problem? I prefer `latex` command for typesetting as it handles the `.eps` files better. I work in a linux environment. Below is a minimal compilable code that used. `puthesis` is a style file for Purdue University thesis.

```
\documentclass[me,dissertation]{puthesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{import}
\begin{document}
\subimport{introduction/}{c.tex}
\subimport{summary/}{c.tex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thank you for the edits and the clarification. I was a little confused with that edit before.

Comment: @Srinivas OK, I'll tidy up the comments shortly

Comment: I tried your `MWE` and it worked with both `latex` and `pdflatex`, i.e. it includes the content of the files in the subdirectory. Are you using the newest `puthesis` class file?

Comment: @Christian I tried the latest puthesis class file. I still have the problem. Here, is the error.      TexLive 2012
(./t.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
(./puthesis.cls
Document Class: puthesis 2012/11/30
(/package/texlive/2012/amd64-RedHatEL/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
! LaTeX Error: File `introduction' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.4   \includegraphics{introduction}
                                    
?

Comment: @Christian. Thank you for your suggestion. I was able to fix the problem. I was using figures in <pdf> format which do not work with <latex>. Using the <eps> versions of the figures resolved my problem.

Comment: All in all, I'd recommend sticking with `pdflatex`. Most/all modern TeX systems include the ability to automatically convert EPS files to equivalent PDFs. And `pdflatex` lets you include JPEG and PNG files, too, in case you have screenshots, photos, or other similar content. `latex` only supports EPS, and normally doesn't convert anything automatically. I've seen orders of magnitude size differences between the files needed for a PDF workflow and a EPS one when JPEGs and PNGs needed to be converted.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Mike. I saw the difference too. EPS files are huge in size compared to their corresponding PNGs or JPEGs, especially for pictures or screenshots.